# next.js create enother function like initialprops to call API from serverside

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to fetch data with functions rather than `oninitialprops`. How can I do that?

For example another function name `testfunction(){}` ***needs to fetch an API from serverside***.

How can this be done?

Comment: You can create any functions in `methods` section & call it in `created` if you want to call it onload

Comment: Do you have any code to show? Then only people can help you with that. [This might help you.](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching)

Comment: starter code on site i want to call serverside when on click currently fetch from another site blocking by cors